# Does a fixed size array specify the maximum size or the exact size of the array?

Tags: solidity, arrays

Basically, I just want to know if a bool[5] array will hold exactly 5 booleans, or can it hold less than 5 booleans as well?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this depends on what you mean with "holding".

If you create array of type `bool` with static size of 5, it means you will immediately have an array of types `bool` with 5 entries, and all entries have the value `false`. So in a sense the array is already "filled".

There is no concept of "null" or empty in Solidity. All types have a default value which is used. For booleans, this is "false". For all integer types, this is "0".

So your array will always contain exactly 5 entries. If you don't set them to anything, they will be false.